# Trouble modularizing passport.js with node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

so I'm sort of having an issue here.  I have my login route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
require('../config/passport')(passport, LocalStrategy);


/* GET /login */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //you'll probably write some 
res.render('login', { title: 'Please Log In' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
console.log('posting');
console.log(passport);
passport.initialize();
passport.session();
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                 failureRedirect: '/login'
                                });
console.log('after');
});
module.exports = router;
```

my app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
  path = require('path'),
  favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
  logger = require('morgan'),
  cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  session = require('express-session'), 
  RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session),
  passport = require('passport'),

  //  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
  pool = require('./config/database'),

  routes = require('./routes/index'),
  api = require('./routes/api'),
  login = require('./routes/login'),

  app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session(<<redis store info>>);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/login', login);
...etc
```

and my ./config/passport.js

```
var pool = require('./database');

module.exports = function(passport, LocalStrategy) {


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    mysql.query("select * from users where id = "+id,function(err,rows){    
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, username, password, done) { // callback with user and password from our form
    console.log('hi');
     pool.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '" + username + "'",function(err,rows){
        if (err)
            return done(err);
         if (!rows.length) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
        } 

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!( rows[0].password == password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        // all is well, return successful user
        return done(null, rows[0]);         

    });

}));

};
```

And I can't really understand why the passport config just doesn't seem to be getting processed at all.  When I call passport.authenticate it's seemingly doing nothing

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong here. Ever read the [documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there were a few things I did to get this to work.  The first is I moved the following into passport.js  Having anything inside require() passport related in my route was nuts.  I started without this mess, but trying to tinker had progressed to that point.  Furthermore, my deserialize function incorrectly had a mysql reference instead of my pool.

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

I then just set up passport like normal in the config, and did

```
module.exports = passport;
```

Then just did this in app.js:

```
var passport = require('../config/passport');
```

then I changed my router, removed essentially the whole thing on the post function, and did:

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                  failureRedirect: '/login'
                                                 }));
```

I learned I couldn't just call passport.authenticate.  It was meant to be placed in a req handler.

Sorry for the totally insane and ambiguous question guys.  Just in case any poor soul looks for this down the line, I figured I at least need to have the courtesy to talk about it.